# Edit a specific line of a text document

Tags: c, edit

Is there any specifc way to edit an idividual line of a text document? I currently have a program that can find what line the section I want to edit is on, but I don't know if there is a way to rewrite the specific line in the document without copying the entire document to another document line by line and editing the desired one in passing, then writing it all back to the original file.

Is there any way to write over an individual line in a document provided you have the line you want to edit?

Comment: No it's impossible. Basically you need to read all lines of the file, modify the line(s) you want, and write them to a file. Inother words you cannot insert/delete content into/from a file directly.

Comment: It can only be done if your new line is exactly as long as the original line, and that is a *serious* drawback. Files don't work the way you think they do.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - what about using a combination of ftel, fseek, fgets - if he knows the position of the line, and the number of chars in this line including '\n' and just overwrite this line by fprintf with the same number of chars with '\n' at the end of the line. wouldnt that work?
it will work. think about it.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://codeforwin.org/2018/02/c-program-replace-specific-line-a-text-file.html) one? Might be it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Adam And if the new line is longer than the old one?

Comment: It is possible only under certain circumstances. Those of a file strictly designed and controlled by yourself (on your team/company) in which the structure has by design a fixed line length, for example something line _"000001,234567890,"20_CHARS_LONG_STRING"\n"_

Comment: I've been lazy and just `popen()`ed an `ed` session and altered files that way before instead of trying to do it all in C.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - In this case, he can use some thing else, like, seeking the next line position, copying the whole lines till eof to temp buffer , then re write his line and then the buffer temp. but this is ugly, and not efficient at all if the file is large enough. But he asked if this is possible and the answer is yes and possible in some circumstances. But you have answered No and this is a wrong answer my friend.

Comment: @Adam feel free to write an answer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I will but not now i am too busy for that. thank you.

Comment: Yes you can, or a part line, but only if you are overwriting the exact same length of characters. So you can overwrite `four` with `five` but you can't overwrite `six` with `seven`. If you overwrite `eight` with `nine` there remains a problem what to put for the "spare" charcacter.

Comment: You could do this - 1. Decide if the part of a file needs to be moved - if so, working from the end of the file move chuks either forwards or backwards until you get to the appropriate place. 2. Seek to the correct locating and write in the new text.

Comment: Alternatively create a new file with the correct contents. Remove the old file. Rename the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to replace a line it must be with same length. else you will override other lines. If you have this case you have to rewrite the remaining data.

sample file:

```
a
b
XXXXXXXXXXXX
d
e
```

sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char new_line[]="hello world!";
int target_line_num = 2;
int main(void)
{
   FILE* filePtr = fopen("try.txt", "r+");
   char c;
   int current_line=0;

   while((c = fgetc(filePtr)) != EOF)
   {
       if(c == '\n')
       {
           current_line++;
       }
       if(current_line == target_line_num && c!='\r')
       {
           fseek(filePtr, 0, SEEK_CUR);
           for(int i=0;new_line[i];i++)
           {
            fputc(new_line[i], filePtr);

           }
       }
   }
   fclose(filePtr);
   return 0;
}
```